# crystal reports attempting to link two tables by matching string with no luck

Tags: crystal-reports

As stated in the title, I have two tables I'm attempting to link.  Both Strings appear to be a match, however Crystal Reports is not picking it up.  The only thing I can think is that that length of the field is different, even though the strings are the same.  could that cause a discrepancy?  If so how can I correct for it?  Thank you

Comment: just confirmed that one string is String[10] and the other is String[50].

Comment: I also attempted to link this as a subreport, using a trimmed version of the string, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Length of the string will prevent a match.  If you are using the `Trim(string)` function, that only removes spaces found at the beginning or end of your string, so the two strings could still be of different lengths after using this function.  You will need to use another function to capture a substring of the original string.  To do this you can use the `Left(string, length)` function to ensure both strings are the same length.

If they still do not match then you may have non-printable characters in one or both of your strings.  Carriage Return and Line Feed tend to be the most commonly found non-printable characters.  A Carriage Return is represented as `Chr(10)`, while a Line Feed is represented as `Chr(13)`.  These are Built In Constants similar to those found in VBA and Visual Basic.

You can use a find and replace to remove them with the following formula.  Its not a bad idea to also include the trim and left functions in this as well to ensure you get the best match possible.

```
Replace(Replace(Left(Trim({YourStringField}), 10),Chr(10), ""),Chr(13), "")
```

There are a few additional Built In Constants you may need to check for if this doesn't work.  A Tab is represented as `Chr(9)` for example.  Its very rare for strings to contain the other Built In Constants though.  In most cases Carriage Return and Line Feed are the only ones that are typically found in Plain Text.  Tabs and the other constants should only be found in Rich Text and are very rare in string data.

Comment: Just realized I neglected to respond to this.  Using the left formula fixed the problem.  thank you!!